# How AWS CDK remembers to retain specific logical ids when synthesizing the CF templates?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

CDK is able retain the logical ids of resources on the synthesized templates. You can generate/synth the template multiple times and the outcome will always be the same logical ids.

I just want to know how it manages to accomplish that underneath?